# How can execute multiple statements in one query with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails with ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL.

How can i execute multiple sql queries?

I need it for running a custom migration script, eg:

```
Foo.connection.execute <<-SQL.split(';').map(&:strip).join
 delete from metadata where record_type = 'Foo';
 TRUNCATE table1 RESTART IDENTITY;
 TRUNCATE table2 RESTART IDENTITY;
 delete from schema_migrations where version > '20120806120823';
SQL
```

I am not accepting data from a user, so I'm not worried about sql-injection.

Something like [`CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html) in MySQL maybe ?

From the MySQL/PHP docs:

> **CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS**: Tell the server that the client may send
>   multiple statements in a single string (separated by “;”). If this
>   flag is not set, multiple-statement execution is disabled. See the
>   note following this table for more information about this flag.

Comment: I take it that in the real example you're reading the script from a file, so you can't just loop over `execute` once for each statement without doing dodgy string splitting like the example? If it were directly in your code you could just put the statements in an array and loop over it.

Comment: Hope the edit accurately reflects your intention. Let me know - or re-edit - if not.

Comment: Like what Craig Ringer says—what's wrong with simply calling `connection.execute` multiple times with one statement each? I've done that enough times (once, running a legacy SQL schema dump of dozens of tables as the very first migration in a Rails app).

Comment: do not want to make multiple network calls. That is what i am doing right now though. Network calls are quite slow over the network, in this case, but i can live with it for deletes and truncates. Asked this question mostly to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work out of the box with PostgreSQL, checked with pg gem and rails 3.2:

```
class Multitest < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      create table x(id serial primary key);
      create table y(id serial primary key, i integer);
    SQL
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

On a side note, manipulating `schema_migrations` directly looks strange.

Comment: thanks, i will check the code for migrations. But how does migration's execute work but ActiveRecord's does not? How to run multiple queries from ActiveRecord ?

Comment: Doesn't work for MySQL, though. ActiveRecord's execute succeeds w/ multiple on Postgres, fails on MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

For mysql

```
queries = File.read("/where/is/myqueries.sql")
# or
queries = <<-SQL
 TRUNCATE table1 RESTART IDENTITY;
 TRUNCATE table2 RESTART IDENTITY;
 delete from schema_migrations where version > '20120806120823';
SQL

queries.split(';').map(&:strip).each do |query| 
  execute(query)
end
```

You may want see this question too:
[Invoking a large set of SQL from a Rails 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395618/invoking-a-large-set-of-sql-from-a-rails-4-application)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`:

In `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: project_development
  flags:
    - MULTI_STATEMENTS
```

Then in your code:

```
connection.execute(multistatement_query)
# Hack for mysql2 adapter to be able query again after executing multistatement_query
connection.raw_connection.store_result while connection.raw_connection.next_result
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246837/338859 for details

Comment: You didn't read the question. This is for Postgres, not MySQL.

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad.

Comment: Still useful for me, a mysql user, to come across this answer after googling a generic multi-statement question! :)

Comment: I couldn't get this `MULTI_STATEMENTS` flag to work. To be fair, I didn't try very hard. But I ended up just splitting my statements out and calling `execute` on each one. I only had a few so it ended up being fine and didn't require mucking with MySQL or ActiveRecord.